# Enforce an image to the bottom of page when scrolled (does not scroll with user)

Tags: html, css

So I have an image I want to be at the bottom left of my page.  If the bottom of the page is not visible on load, I want the user to have to scroll down to see it.  Every time I have tried to look this up, everyone wants their image to scroll with the user, and that is NOT what I want.

Here is my current .css

```
#backgroundImageOne{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

And then I implement it in my layout like this:

```
<body>
  <div style="height:100%">
    <div id="placeHolder">
      <div id="backgroundImageOne">
        <img src="/images/background1.png"
      </div>
    </div>
   .
   .
   .
</body>
```

Any help or tips on how to make this stay at the bottom of the page all the time would be extremely helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position: relative;` to the body with css. That should work.

Comment: I tried this as well.  However, it locks it onto the bottom of what I can view when the page loads, not the actual bottom of the page.  And then when I scroll down, it sticks to the middle of the page.

Comment: You should take that div with that picture out of it's parent and place it right after the body tag (of just before the closing body tag). Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jnzrko02/

Comment: Ok.  I have done that as well, same result.  Is it possible that there is a problem because it is in layout not on the actual page?

Comment: No, if you use my fiddle exactly it just should work. Just tested in on my own website

Comment: Ok.  Yeah I was messing up something else stupid, but that works.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
#backgroundImageOne{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

<div id="backgroundImageOne">
    <img src="/images/background1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: When I set to fixed, the image scrolls with the page.

Comment: if you want user scroll the page you can show or hide #backgroundImageOne reading value of scrollTop